# Can calling too many requests cause timeout error?

Tags: node.js, request

In my `node` server, I have a cronjob which calls about 1000 API requests to an `apache PHP` server. At some point, the request causes timeout error.(Each API request takes about 2 seconds). The library I am using is `request`

If I call the 1000 API requests asynchronously, after maybe 100 requests, the remaining requests do not get any returns(timeout error).

I thought I was requesting too much at one go and so the php server could not handle all the requests. So, instead of requesting 1000 times simultaneously, I requested it sequentially(synchronously). This time, about 800 requests were successful, but the remaining 200 still had timeout error.

Since, I was calling sequentially(one at a time), I thought the PHP server should not be the problem. When I used postman to call the same API from the php server, it responded fine. But when I reboot the node server, it worked again until a certain point.

So I am pretty sure that there is something wrong with my node server, but I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: The question lacks essential details: nodejs itself is fine serving 1000 or a million of requests, it must be your or libraries you use code that does something dodgy.

Comment: The library Im using `request`. It seems quite stable..

Comment: It's not obvious what you want from a community then.

Comment: Could it be the cronjob is timing out?  I haven’t used cron in Node, but quartz for java (which does the same thing), has max work units and max millis in which the job should run.

Comment: wow that could be possible, ill check if thats the case.

Comment: @zerkms I am trying to figure out the source of the problem. What I explained above is narrowing down the problem, so some of you guys can suggest what the source could be

Comment: Some of your code, or misconfigured libraries